# make_pair of std::map - how to make a pair only if the key is not listed (and update the key otherwise)?

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, containers

Consider the following code :

```
std::map <string,string> myMap;
myMap.insert(std::make_pair("first_key" , "no_value" ));
myMap.insert(std::make_pair("first_key" , "first_value" ));
myMap.insert(std::make_pair("second_key" , "second_value" ));

typedef map<string, string>::const_iterator MapIterator;
for (MapIterator iter = myMap.begin(); iter != myMap.end(); iter++)
{
    cout << "Key: " << iter->first << endl << "Values:" << iter->second << endl;
}
```

The output is :

```
Key: first_key
Values:no_value
Key: second_key
Values:second_value
```

Meaning is that the second assignment :

```
myMap.insert(std::make_pair("first_key" , "first_value" ));
```

didn't take place .

How can I make a pair , only if the key is not already listed , and if is listed - change its value ?

Is there any generic method of std::map ?

Comment: Why do you need `make_pair`? I mean, what's wrong with a more traditional `myMap["first_key"]="first_value"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a condition before insert

```
if (myMap.find("first_key") == myMap.end()) {
  myMap.insert(std::make_pair("first_key" , "first_value" ));
}
else {
  myMap["first_key"] = "first_value";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `operator []`, or use `find` and change value if key finded.
Will insert pair in map, if there is no such key and update value, if key exists.

```
myMap["first_key"] = "first_value";
```

Or this:

```
auto pos = myMap.find("first_key");
if (pos != myMap.end())
{
   pos->second = "first_value";
}
else
{
   // insert here.
}
```

Comment: +1, for obvious reasons, the former of these is often used in insert-else-update scenarios for its simplicity and *brevity*.

Answer (score 5):

It's more efficient to avoid searching the map a second time when the value is present:

```
const iterator i = myMap.find("first_key");
if (i == myMap.end()) {
    myMap.insert(std::make_pair("first_key" , "first_value"));
} else {
    i->second = "first_value";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <map>
//use of make_pair using map container

std::map< std::string, std::map<std::string, float> > student;
        std::map<std::string, float> data;
           data.insert(make_pair("rollno", 11));
        data.insert(make_pair("Physics", 55));
        data.insert(make_pair("Chemistry", 80));
        data.insert(make_pair("Math", 65));
        student.insert(make_pair("Milind Morey", data));
       
        data.insert(make_pair("rollno", 12));
        data.insert(make_pair("Physics", 40));
        data.insert(make_pair("Chemistry", 90));
        data.insert(make_pair("Math", 77));
        student.insert(make_pair("pankaj B", data));
       
        data.insert(make_pair("rollno", 12));
        data.insert(make_pair("Physics", 84));
        data.insert(make_pair("Chemistry", 59));
        data.insert(make_pair("Math", 76));
        student.insert(make_pair("Sachin D", data));
       
        for (auto s : student)
        {
            std::map<std::string, float> rmrk = s.second;
            cout <<endl<< s.first<<"   ";
            for (auto stddetails : s.second)
            {
                cout <<"   "<< stddetails.first << "   " << stddetails.second;
            }
        }
```